Can this Json format be converted to gRPC propobuf protocol? It seems that nested List is not supported
{
    "spd": 1,
    "chId": 1,
    "sir": 1,
    "doInfos": [
        [
            {
                "wdID": 101,
                "applyId": "666",
                "matchInfor": [
                    {
                        "targetId": "666",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    },
                    {
                        "targetId": "777",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "wdID": 101,
                "applyId": "666",
                "matchInfor": [
                    {
                        "targetId": "666",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    },
                    {
                        "targetId": "777",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "wdID": 101,
                "applyId": "666",
                "matchInfor": [
                    {
                        "targetId": "666",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    },
                    {
                        "targetId": "888",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "wdID": 101,
                "applyId": "666",
                "matchInfor": [
                    {
                        "targetId": "666",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    },
                    {
                        "targetId": "888",
                        "score": -107374176.0,
                        "X": 2.0,
                        "Y": 3.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}

Unable to generate corresponding protocol structure

Yes, as I see you can create these types of messages:
message SomeMessage{
  int64 spd = 1;
  int64 chId = 2;
  int64 sir = 3;
  repeated DoInfosItem doInfos = 4;
}
message DoInfosItem{
  int64 wdId = 1;
  string applyId = 2;
  repeated MatchInforItem matchInfor = 3;
}
message MatchInforItem{
  string targetId = 1;
  double score = 2;
  double X = 3;
  double Y = 4;
}

